# Maven Project Properties

Tags: maven, build

In my Maven pom.xml, I have seen following thing;

```
project.build.sourceDirectory
project.build.scriptSourceDirectory
project.build.testSourceDirectory
project.build.outputDirectory
project.build.testOutputDirectory
project.build.directory
```

Where exactly are these defined? How do I know what location they represent locally ?

Comment: google: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM

Comment: you should find that these should have sensible default values, unless you want to override them

Answer (score 0):

As Stewart says, these are defined in the Super POM ([Introduction to the POM - Super POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM)).

To see the values they have for a project, run `mvn help:effective-pom` to show your project's POM merged with the definitions from the Super POM:

```
...
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>XXX/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>XXX/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>XXX/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>XXX/target/classes</outputDirectory>
...
```

You can override these values in your own projects; using the properties to refer to them means that plugins referring to these paths will pick up the overridden values.